# Titanim Mobile Tabgroup

Tags: tabs, titanium-mobile

I've a tabgroup with two tabs in each tab i user a alert dialog but it is only shown once.

I start the app first tab get's opened and alert dialog is shown, then i switch to the second tab and back to the first but in this case no alert dialog is shown. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

you have to use `tabGroup.addEventListener` to get the alert dialog, add the below code in your tabGroup page. Hope this helps you

```
tabGroup.addEventListener('focus', function(event) {
  Ti.API.info("current tab index = "+event.index);
  Ti.API.info("previous tab index = "+event.previousIndex);
});
```